# VBA 7.0 in Excel, Line Input appears to add extra quotes around the line

Tags: vba, excel, file-handling

I have a file with lines like:

> one
>   two
>   three

When I read from one file and write to another, they end up quoted.  They are also quoted within the variable in the watch window.

Also when I have a file with:

> "one", "two", "three"

It ends up written as:

> """one"", ""two"", ""three"""

Does anyone know what is causing this?  My files have extension ".txt".
Thank you for your time.

Sample code snippet below:

```
Public Sub ReadAndWrite()

Dim fhInput As Integer
Dim fhOutput As Integer
Dim strSingleLine As String

fhInput = FreeFile()

Open "<your input file here>" For Input As #fhInput

fhOutput = FreeFile()

Open "<your output file here>" For Output As #fhOutput

Do While Not EOF(fhInput)
    Line Input #fhInput, strSingleLine
    Write #fhOutput, strSingleLine
Loop

Close (fhInput)
Close (fhOutput)

End Sub
```

Comment: In this case you'd better copy the source file to the destination file.

Comment: This is a cut down example to demonstrate the behavour only, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the `Write` statement that puts quotes round the strings. You should use `Print` instead if you don't want that.

Comment: This answer is correct, thank you, sorry I don't have the points to "up" your answer.